# 3 x 146 GB scsi hdd data recovery

Tags: data-recovery, scsi

Bought a new server with sff sata hdds.  Before I got a chance to install the new server the old HP ProLiant DL385 Opteron 8218 with 3 x 146 gb scsi hdds has failed.  I think the hard discs themselves are fine.

Is there a way to get the data off the old drives without going to a third party data specialist?  I assume I cannot just take the drives out and put them in a SCSI adapter as the hdd order matters?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how the disks where used, on what OS and on what controller to determine this. Hardware RAID will be a problem, but if you presented the disks as individual devices and used e.g. Linux MD RAID or LVM, the order shouldn't matter too much (provided you don't want to boot from the disks). Unlike PATA/USB adapters, I've never seen any Parallel-SCSI-to-anything adapters though, so you'll likely need a working controller.

Comment: Your statement could be clearer - have the disks failed at all or just the server? it's not clear - if the disks have failed I don't understand the 'I think the hard discs themselves are fine' bit - if they aren't failed then just fix the server or put them into another similar/identical one. By the way, the DL385 never came with the 8212, that was a DL585 processor, and that didn't support SFF disks - can you confirm what you actually have please

Comment: I think the "server failed". More detail on what "failed" means would be helpful.

Comment: Ok sorry for not being clear.  I have no idea what happened to the server: it suddenly stopped responding during the day. A power button reboot left it frozen on the HP Proliant splash screen.  I think the HDDs are OK as all led indicator lights are fine.  The O/S is windows server 2008 R1.  I won't fix the server as I have already purchased a new one and do not want to spend time trying to fix such an old server.

Comment: Ok, thanks for coming back to us - the disks should just work fine so long as you plug them into another HP SmartArray controller of the same or new model spec as the one they came out of - you don't even need to put them in the same slot - the disks themselves carry a bunch of data on a special part of the disk that allows the controller to know what they used to do and it will try to make them do the same.